# PostgreSQL: How to insert only one backslash into PostgreSQL database

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

Does anyone know how to store a single backslash into PostgreSQL Database?

I am using C# and Nqgsql to access PostgreSQL, and my case is I want to store "1\\0\\0\\0\\1\\0" into the database, and the expected string in DB field will be "1\0\0\0\1\0", that is I only need one backslash in the db field, thus when I get the data from db, it will still be "1\\0\\0\\0\\1\\0"  in memory. But my problem is when the memory string is "1\\0\\0\\0\\1\\0", the string stored into db field is also "1\\0\\0\\0\\1\\0", then when I get the data from db, the memory string will be "1\\\\0\\\\0\\\\0\\\\1\\\\0".

The variables I used in c# code is set as the following format:
var a = "1\\0\\0\\0\\1\\0";
var b = @"1\0\0\0\1\0";

when store into db, it seems that the backslashes in both variables have been doubled. How to deal with this issue?

Comment: What is your Postgres version and what is the value of the configuration setting `standard_conforming_strings`

Comment: While my Postgres version is "postgresql-9.2.1-1-windows-x64", and by default the "standard_conforming_strings" is on, I did not change that. By the way, I use EntityFramework 5.0 and Npgsql as provider, so I don't use parametrized queries or queries by code directly.

Comment: The  latest code in the following code has fixed the issue I reported:    https://github.com/magnitudo/Npgsql2/commit/faa6134c40779936ca747903ef503dd2c8ee6e71

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid this entirely by using parametrized queries. Consult an example in [Npgsql: User's Manual](http://npgsql.projects.pgfoundry.org/docs/manual/UserManual.html) in *Using parameters in a query* section.

But if you really want to construct a literal query then you can use `E''` syntax, like this:

```
var sql = @"insert into table_name (column_name) values (E'1\\0\\0\\0\\1\\0')";
```

This syntax is independent of server or connection configuration like `standard_conforming_strings`. But it is Postgres specific.

If you want your code be portable between different database engines the you can issue `set standard_conforming_strings=on` just after connecting. Then this works:

```
var sql = @"insert into table_name (column_name) values ('1\0\0\0\1\0')";
```

This option is turned on by default since PostgreSQL 9.1 and available since 8.2.

Comment: Thanks Tometzky. But that could not fix my issue. While my Postgres version is "postgresql-9.2.1-1-windows-x64", and by default the "standard_conforming_strings" is on, I did not change that. By the way, I use EntityFramework 5.0 and Npgsql as provider, so I don't use parametrized queries or queries by code directly.

Comment: If you're using an ORM like EntityFramework then I'm pretty sure that you're over-thinking things. You don't escape a string to put into a database - you just set a property of a database mapped object and make it save itself - that's it. No escaping, no SQL queries, just objects and its properties. We can't help you more unless you show us the code.

Comment: The  latest code in the following code has fixed the issue I reported:    https://github.com/magnitudo/Npgsql2/commit/faa6134c40779936ca747903ef503dd2c8ee6e71

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem as well.  I was able to solve it by going in the database's config and changing "standard_conforming_strings" to OFF.